# How can I access application deployed on localhost of AWS remote server?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have developed a set of apis on my AWS server.
When I do npm start , application is started on a particular port of aws localhost.
I am able to hit the apis using curl command from my terminal window.
eg:

```
curl -s -X GET \
"http://localhost:6001/getAssetDetails?assetId=1"\
-H "content-type: application/json"
```

How to access the apis from my host system using postman installed on my host machine?

How to access localhost applications of AWS server from web browser of windows host? What URL should I hit from my host machine?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Inbound rules in Access control list (ACL) of your EC2 instance. Ports are blocked by default in aws server. This might help [aws-doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the input Saqib.  I have done changes to Security group as suggested in Documentation.(Added http and https in inbound rules).  and now trying to hit url - http://<IPaddress>:8080 where my api is started from host machine , but still not able to access the api.  am I missing something here?

Comment: Depends on how you're starting the server. To expose an API to outside (remote) you would have to start the Server on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 because localhost is a loopback address it cant be accessed from remote machines

Comment: Try something like http.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0").